# Why is the range of the timestamp type 4713 BC to 294276 AD?

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql has a `timestamp` datatype with resolution 1 microsecond and range 4713 BC to 294276 AD that takes up 8 bytes (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

I have calculated the total number of microseconds in that range as (294276 + 4713) × 365.25 × 24 × 60 × 60 × 1000000 = 9.435375266×10¹⁸. This is less than 2⁶⁴ = 1.844674407×10¹⁹, but also more than 2⁶³ = 9.223372037×10¹⁸.

I might be off by a few days due to calendar weirdness and leap years, but I don't think it's enough to push the number below 2⁶³.

So, why were the limits chosen like that? Why not use the full range available with 64 bits?

Comment: So what is your actual problem? Do you need to store date values outside of that range?

Comment: For the explanation see the source [timestamp.h](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/include/datatype/timestamp.h;h=99873497a6d6cf2f1891a80fac804271457422f5;hb=HEAD) roughly lines 125:175

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, I'm just curious

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this says that the max for dates is 5874897 AD which is pretty close to 2^64. Still doesn't explain the range for timestamps.

Comment: See @LaurenzAlbe answer. I should have pointed out the `#define POSTGRES_EPOCH_JDATE    2451545 /* == date2j(2000, 1, 1) */` in the above line range and the ` /* Timestamp limits */` section at ~line 183.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal representation of timestamps is in microseconds since `2000-01-01 00:00:00`, stored as an 8-byte integer. So the maximum possible year would be something like

```
SELECT (2::numeric^63 -1) / 365.24219 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000000 + 2000;

        ?column?         
═════════════════════════
 294277.2726976055146158
(1 row)
```

which explains the upper limit.

The minimum is explained by a comment in `src/include/datatype/timestamp.h`:

```
/*
 * Range limits for dates and timestamps.
 *
 * We have traditionally allowed Julian day zero as a valid datetime value,
 * so that is the lower bound for both dates and timestamps.
 *
 * The upper limit for dates is 5874897-12-31, which is a bit less than what
 * the Julian-date code can allow.  For timestamps, the upper limit is
 * 294276-12-31.  The int64 overflow limit would be a few days later; again,
 * leaving some slop avoids worries about corner-case overflow, and provides
 * a simpler user-visible definition.
 */
```

So the minimum is taken from the lower limit on Julian dates.

Comment: What I was missing is the fact that 4713 is the the start of the current Julian Period (apparently a system used in Astronomy). Without that information, this date seemed totally arbitrary.